# can't get textarea field using jquery rte lwrte?(  issues of  plugin behaviour I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor

I am using this plugin http://code.google.com/p/lwrte/, but I can not select the textarea or  the id with jquery, I know it creates an iframe, but I read the docs and It does not mention anything about this issue, I just want to count the characters in the textarea and then that the user can not type, but I dont find a solution for this, has someone has a solution? what can I do?

```
<textarea id="message" rows="10" cols="120" class="rte1"></textarea>


$('#message').keyup(function(){ //tried with this does not work


            });
```

any more help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$('message')` with `$('#message')` to get the actual element.

Comment: I tried with that but still does not work and  If I delete the class in the textarea It works

Comment: @RickSalad  Why are you creating a 'blur' handler inside the 'keyup' handler? Remove the `$(this.iframe).blur` handler and just `alert` from inside the 'keyup' handler.

Comment: I tried with that too but does not work I mean It a issue in the plugin

Answer (score 2):

LWRTE takes textAreas and turns them into `<iframe>`s.  So you need to use something like Google Chrome or Firebug to identify the new name of the object, then reference that directly.  Something like this:

```
$('body iframe').contents().find('body').html()
```